# Scoped storage - is it still possible to get image Uri by absolute path, without SAF?

Tags: android, uri, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I understand that from api 29 we need to work with URI and Image id's to perform bitmap operations, but in order to migrate from image path to uri i'll need to drop real users databases and server databases, and if there is a way to avoid this i would like to try.
For example i got "FileNotFoundExeption: no content provider" error here:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(path)), new Rect(), options);
```

Thanks!

edits:

path is absolute file path like /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20200128_122949_020.jpg

Here in code snippet i'm trying to decode image bounds, e.g. to get width and height of image on filesystem by path of image.

Comment: The question is about images, that are accessible with MediaStore

Comment: If you dont tell the value of `path` we dont know what you are doiing.

Comment: `i'll need to drop real users databases and server databases, `. I dont see any reason for that. And you did not tell why.

Comment: `I understand that from api 29 we need to work with URI and Image id's to perform bitmap operations,`. No you still can use classic file paths in a lot of situations.

Comment: And most bitmap operations dont need a path or an uri so it is pretty unclear where your post is about. You might rephrase it.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your comments! i've edit my question, please take a look. I'll need to drop databases to store image id or uri instead of path to be able to open input stream or get image from content resolver. Any other ways that i tried leads me to fileNotFoundExeption and permissionDenied

Comment: You should put your explanations in your post. Not in a comment. Any idea what `Uri.parse(path)` delivers?